# Dashed border with border-image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three overlaying layer 2 with background image and 11 or the content.

In the content i placed a input button tag with dashed boarder.

what i was trying to achieve is to get the same background layer image from layer 1 only on the dashes.

Obvious background:transparent isn't working so for second choice i used the input boarder and tried to mock this behavior by setting boarder-image to the background image from layer 1.

[image]

```
.button {
font-family:verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
background: transparent;
border-width:5px;
border-style:dashed;
border-color: black; }
```

So all dashes around the submit button should have the same background like the first layer on the left

I changed it to:

[image]

```
.button {
font-family:verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
background: transparent;
border-width:5px;
border-style:dashed;
border-color: black;
border-image: url(/img/bg1.jpg); }
```

i don't have any idea how to achieve the dashed look with boarder-image

with: border-image: url(/img/bg1.jpg) 30 30 round;
[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/6vKdh/3/

Comment: If what is shown in the first image is what you want to achieve, then I don’t see how a simple dashed border would fail to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS `border-image` Syntax is like this:

`border-image: source slice width outset repeat|initial|inherit;`

So you are missing something there.

try replace your `border-image`

```
border-image: url(/img/bg1.jpg);
```

for this example:

```
border-image: url(/img/bg1.jpg) 30 30 round;
```

for more Documentation look at this : **[CSS3 Border-Image](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/)**

Comment: tried this before but still losing the dashes, i added a screenshot in my question.

Comment: can you set up a Fiddle with your image so we can better help you?

Comment: sorry I can't understand your problem, the submit button shows dashed border liked nav buttons.

Comment: yes but i want the black dashes to have the bg1.jpg background not black color.

Comment: what about doing background-image dashed? here is a demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k3j2J/2/  I used a image from google. So please use yours. And let me know if this helps you.